# Consolidate rows in one table based on duplicates in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have one table `table1` that might look like this, where there could be duplicates on 2 fields `Cnumber` and `Dob` and then unique `pkSID`:

```
pkSID     Cnumber     Dob  
1         12345       01/02/2002
2         12345       01/02/2002
3         12345       01/02/2002
4         12345       01/02/2002
5         12345       01/02/2002
```

There can be multiple occurrences of this in `table1`. I then have another table that references the `pkSID`, and I want to consolidate those rows so they all only reference one of the `pkSID` in `table1`, so `table2` will look like this initially:

```
pkSTID    fkSID    OtherVal1    OtherVal2
1         1        s            x
2         2        t            f
3         3        a            d
4         4        v            g
5         5        b            z
```

And then after the consolidation:

```
pkSTID    fkSID    OtherVal1    OtherVal2
1         1        s            x
2         1        t            f
3         1        a            d
4         1        v            g
5         1        b            z
```

How can I find those rows in `table1` and then consolidate in `table2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Note: I'm considering pkSID is in continuation for relative Cnumber and Dob

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1(pkSID INT,Cnumber INT,Dob  DATE)

INSERT INTO #TABLE1
SELECT 1, 12345, '01/02/2002' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 12345, '01/02/2002' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 12345, '01/02/2002' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 12345, '01/02/2002' UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 12345, '01/02/2002'

CREATE TABLE #TABLE2(pkSTID INT,fkSID INT,OtherVal1  VARCHAR(10),OtherVal2 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TABLE2
SELECT 1, 1, 's', 'x' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 't', 'f' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 'a', 'd' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 'v', 'g' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 'b', 'z'


SELECT  T2.pkSTID, T3.min_pkSID fkSID, T2.OtherVal1 , T2.OtherVal2 
FROM #TABLE2 T2
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT  MIN(T1.pkSID) min_pkSID, MAX(T1.pkSID) max_pkSID FROM #TABLE1 T1 GROUP BY T1.Cnumber, T1.Dob --T1 ON T2.fkSID = T1.pkSID
)T3 
ON T2.fkSID BETWEEN T3.min_pkSID AND T3.max_pkSID
```